# tikz unwanted space between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following MWE illustrates the problem: between connectected fill areas is a small gap, where the background will be displayed (see the zoomed in picture with the red marks)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{green}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm and 6mm]
  \node (b1) [text width=10mm, text height=10mm,fill=white]{};
  \node (b2) [text width=10mm, text height=10mm,fill=black,right=of b1]{};
  \fill[black] (b1.north east) -- (b2.north west) -- (b2.south west) -- (b1.south east) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What can I do to avoid the background image between the filled areas?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make `outer sep` equal to zero.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{green}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm and 6mm]
  \node (b1) [text width=10mm, text height=10mm,fill=white,outer sep=0pt]{};
  \node (b2) [text width=10mm, text height=10mm,fill=black,right=of b1,outer sep=0pt]{};
  \fill[black] (b1.north east) -- (b2.north west) -- (b2.south west) -- (b1.south east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange - there is one pixel(rgb=0,27,0) shining through between the black areas.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen It shouldn't be there. Not in Adobe for me. May be an artefact of viewer.

Comment: It is there - on your picture.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen I took it from sumatrapdf. In adobe it isn't seen.